# Why doesn't the number of ones in the binary representation of Fibonacci numbers grow linearly?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I am a third-year computer science student. I am interested, why doesn't the number of ones in the binary representation of Fibonacci numbers grow linearly? I would expect it to grow linearly all the time (because the Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially with the index, and the number of binary ones is proportional to the logarithm, so the exponential growth and logarithmic growth should cancel each other out into the linear growth), but apparently it grows linearly up to around the 45th Fibonacci number... and then it stops growing. How is that possible?

[image: The number of ones in the binary representation of Fibonacci numbers grows linearly up to around 45th Fibonacci number, and then it stops growing.]

Comment: Similarly, every sum of positive reals converges when computing with floating reals on computers, addition and multiplication fail to be associatif (rounding errors) and $\sum_{i=1}^N 1/i$ is strictly smaller than $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}1/(N-i)$ when working with floating numbers for $N\sim 10^9$.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are hitting overflow with 32 bit "integers" at the point where things stop off in your calculations. In other words, your graph stops being accurate because you are using machine numeric types which only store 32 bits, not the full number.

Comment: This seems to be it: the least Fibonacci number more than $2^{32}$ is $F_{48}$. The sequence of binary weights is [0,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,3,2,5,4,2,5,6,4,8,7,4,5,8,6,8,11,6,6,9,11,11,12,8,11,9,13,12,11,12,14,10,12,16,17,14,16,18,15,21,13,12,18,18,17,17,17,16,22,21,16,24,20,16,19,26,23,20,25,19,26,15,23,23,22,25,27,24,23,23,22,27,28,27,32,31,25,30,34,27,33,24,36,33,30,37,28,33,30,29,31,36,38,41,30,31,39,40,34,39,32,35,34,39,42,36,41,43,43,40,43,41,43,36,46,48,37,38,47,37,36,50,46,42,42,42,43,50,46,40,49,36,51,53,50,54,52,48,41,47,49,54,57,55,56,54,50,52,58,54,58,51,51,58,51,59,50,54,59,69,47,... ]

Comment: It is good for MathOverflow to be discussing math overflow.

Comment: I imagine there must have been some temptation to just reply that the reason was that $48\log \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is very close to $32 \log 2$.

Comment: Would've been fun to see the graph at $F_{2^{30} \times 3}$.

Comment: But how do you know that the programming language they are using doesn't have [some neat way](https://superuser.com/q/698312/124630) to compute with numbers beyond 32 bit integers? A system being 32 bits means only that the machine word has 32 digits, but this system could still perform computation of much larger numbers.

Comment: Of course it's possible to compute with numbers of arbitrary length. That's what they should do. They are not currently doing that, as evidenced by their graph and question.

Comment: @SridharRamesh But what are you assuming? Do you know that the number of 1's grow linearly?

Comment: I correctly ran the calculation myself for the numbers in the range they have graphed. Their graph is wrong and it is wrong in the manner caused by only looking at 32 bits. A correct calculation shows the number of 1s grows roughly linearly in this range. I don't understand why you are taking issue with this.

Comment: See also the comment by Mark Wildon above, providing the correct results in this range.

Comment: @SridharRamesh I thought you assumed that "32bits computers could only handle 32 bit numbers" or something like that.

Comment: To clarify my above comment on the fun of seeing the graph at $F_{2^{30} \times 3}$: This is the first value after $F_0$ at which the number of 1s in the least significant 32 bits drops to zero.

Comment: @RedBanana "32-bit computers can only handle 32-bit numbers" is a bit like saying that "10-digit primates can only handle 10-digit numbers"... :-)

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I know. But I've seen people say that sometimes.